# Unexpected behavior with a string stored in a variable in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, variables, control-characters

I'm getting some odd behavior from Excel's `Cells.Find()` method:

Variable I'm searching on:

```
PS > $volumename
vol_01       

PS > $volumename.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                            
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

produces no results:

```
PS > $sheet.Cells.Find($volumename).Row
```

but if I manually copy and paste the value of that variable:

```
PS > $volumename = "vol_01"
PS > $volumename.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                            
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Gets the value I am expecting:

```
PS > $sheet.Cells.Find($volumename).Row
198
```

They appear to be exactly the same type in every way to me.  This doesn't happen for every case.  Some volume names passthrough fine while others do not.  I did scrub the volume name for this post as it has a customers naming convention.  It is the same format as above and the same format as the volume names that work.

Comment: How did you manage opening a powershell terminal within an Excel sheet?

Comment: I'm not.  I'm opening the excel sheet in powershell.

Comment: Use `[int[]] [char[]] 'hello' | % { '0x{0:x} {1}' -f $_, [char] $_ }` to inspect the string for hidden control characters.

Comment: @mklement0, Interesting.  I am seeing some extraneous invisible characters at the end of the string with hex code 0xa0.  How would I trim that off? string replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet can be used to **inspect a string for hidden control characters**:

```
PS> & { [int[]] [char[]] $Args[0] | 
      % { '0x{0:x} [{1}]' -f $_, [char] $_ } } "vol_01`n"

0x76 [v]
0x6f [o]
0x6c [l]
0x5f [_]
0x30 [0]
0x31 [1]
0xa [
]
```

The first column is each character's Unicode code point ("ASCII code"), and the second column the character itself, enclosed in `[...]`

Note that I've added `` "`n" `` at the end of the string - a [newline character (`U+000A`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm) - whose code point expressed as a hex. number is `0xa`.

If, as in your case, the only unwanted part of the string is *trailing whitespace*, you can remove it as follows:

```
$volumename.TrimEnd() # trim trailing whitespace
```

In your case, the trailing whitespace is `0xa0`, the [NO-BREAK SPACE (`U+00A0`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm), which `.TrimEnd()` also removes, as [Tom Blodget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2226988/tom-blodget) points out.

---

Simple **function wrapper** based on the above, for use with pipeline input:

```
filter debug-Chars { [int[]] [char[]] $_ | % { '0x{0:x} [{1}]' -f $_, [char] $_ } }
```

Sample use:

```
"vol_01`n" | debug-Chars
```

---

A **more sophisticated function**, named **`Debug-String`**, is available as [an MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1): It uses PowerShell's own escape-sequence notation to represent control characters in the input string, and also visualizes spaces as `·` by default; adding `-UnicodeEscapes` uses escape sequences for *all* non-ASCII-range characters.

Here's an example that first downloads and defines the function:

```
# Download and define the Debug-String function.
# NOTE: 
#  I can personally assure you that doing this is safe, but you
#  you should always check the source code first.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1/raw/Debug-String.ps1 | iex

"A b`nThis is a hyphen: '-', this is an en dash '–'" | Debug-String -SingleLine
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The codepoint in question is U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE. .Trim() and TrimEnd() do remove it, too. Also, a PowerShell char is a UTF-16 code unit, not a Unicode codepoint (just like in the rest of .NET and many other environments since VB4 and Java). U+00A0 needs one UTF-16 code unit `[char]0x00a0`

Comment: Thanks for the NO-BREAK SPACE correction, @TomBlodget - I've updated the answer accordingly. As for code point vs. code unit. True, PowerShell chars. are UTF-16 code units, but every code unit is also a Unicode code point. But not every code point by itself is a Unicode character (and thus not every .NET character is necessarily a full Unicode character).