# Invoke-WebRequest Select-Object -Expand Content do not return the full content

Tags: powershell

I have now wasted a lot of time on this just can't see what I'm doing wrong
I have looked all over the net and a lot of PowerShell guides use this and the examples work fine on my end as well but when I try this on my data it does not work...

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $APIURLaction -Headers $headers -Method $action -UseBasicParsing
$response
$response | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

Outputs

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"clientProperties":[{"clientProps":{"iSCSIPort":3260,"clusterType":0},"client":{"evmgrcPort":0,"cvdPort":8400,"clientEntity":
                    {"hostName":"CommServe","clientId":2,"clientName":"commserve","_typ...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-Length: 267
                    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
                    Date: Mon, 15 Oct 2018 11:48:26 GMT
                    Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
                    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

                    {"clientProperties":[{...
Forms             :
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 267], [Content-Type, application/json; charset=utf-8], [Date, Mon, 15 Oct 2018 11:48:26 GMT], [Server,
                    Microsoft-IIS/10.0]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        :
RawContentLength  : 267

}hostName":"CommServe","clientId":2,"clientName":"commserve","_type_":3,"clientGUID":"6D658775-D8C1-4D1D-8D0A-42702AB75A63"
```

and as you can clearly see `| Select-Object -Expand Content` does not return the content only the last line... the same goes for `$response.Content` :(

And I can not figure out why hope you can help

Comment: Sort-of unrelated to the question, but `Invoke-RestMethod` should take care of parsing the JSON into a PowerShell object on the fly, should that be what you need.

Comment: Perhaps the string only _appears_ to be single-line on output due to embedded isolated CR characters or other hidden control chars.; inspect it character by character, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648684/45375), for example.