# How do I match on wsl output in powershell?

Tags: powershell, select-string

I want to see if I'm running a particular wsl distribution (Windows 10 Home, WSL 2):

```
PS C:\Users\User> wsl --list --running
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default)
MyDistro
PS C:\Users\User> wsl --list --running | Select-String -Pattern "MyDistro"
PS C:\Users\User>
```

No output. I used `Get-Member` to see that the output is a string; if I run it through something like `| Out-String -stream` it makes no difference.

I *can* get a match with `Select-String .` or `Select-String .*` but it matches everything, which isn't helpful.

Yes, I want to see if there's a running distro with a particular name. Is there a better way to do that in PowerShell?

Answer (score 12):

**Inexplicably, `wsl --list --running` produces UTF-16LE-encoded ("Unicode"-encoded) output** by default instead of respecting the console's active code page, which defaults to the legacy system locale's OEM code page.

---

**Update**: As noted in [Vimes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77074573/45375), v0.64 and above of `wsl.exe` (verify via the first line output by `wsl.exe --version`) now support setting the **`WSL_UTF8` environment variable** to **`1`** to make `wsl.exe` output UTF-8-encoded output:

```bash
$env:WSL_UTF8 = 1
wsl --list --running | Select-String -Pattern MyDistro
```

This **works, as long as your distro names comprise *ASCII*-range characters only** (which seems likely), given that  UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, just like the OEM code pages are; **if *not***, i.e. in the (unlikely) event that your distros contain non-ASCII-range characters (e.g. accented characters such as `é`):

- If you happen to have configured your system to use UTF-8 *system-wide*, (in which case both the OEM and the ANSI code pages *are* UTF-8 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375)), the above solution works as-is.
- Otherwise, use the proper workaround below or - *with* `$env:WSL_UTF8 = 1` in effect - use the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77877265/45375).

---

***Without* use of `$env:WSL_UTF8`**:

A **quick-and-dirty workaround** - which assumes that all running distros are described only with *ASCII-range* characters (which seems likely) - is to use the following:

```bash
(wsl --list --running) -replace "`0" | Select-String -Pattern MyDistro
```

A **proper workaround** that supports all Unicode characters requires more effort:

```bash
$prev = [Console]::OutputEncoding; [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
wsl --list --running | Select-String -Pattern MyDistro
[Console]::OutputEncoding = $prev
```

Comment: Wow, how did you figure that out?

Comment: @Vimes, I analyzed the `wsl.exe` output character by character, using the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648684/45375).

Answer (score 2):

I just [found](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4607#issuecomment-1203237214) that `$env:WSL_UTF8=1` makes wsl.exe output UTF8. Select-String and More seem to work now!

(Prevoius answer: If you don't need regex then `Select-String -simplematch` seems to work.)

Comment: +1 for the `$env:WSL_UTF8` hint (I took the liberty of updating my answer based on it). As for the previous answer: note that regex vs. literal string search is a red herring; the only cause of the problem is the misinterpretation of the UTF-16LE output by PowerShell, before any subsequent command sees the resulting .NET string.