# how capture stdout output into string that regex can be applied against?

Tags: powershell

I want to run a powershell script which will run the `wsl --status` command, capture the stdout output into a variable and then use `Regex` to return the name of the default distribution.

Problem is, the stdout output contains what appears to be nulls or spaces between each character.

How to capture stdout into a variable where the text is something I can run a regex against?

```
$cmdOutput = &wsl --status | Out-String
Write-Output $cmdOutput 

$pattern = "Default Distribution:\s+([\d\w-_\.]+)"
$results = [Regex]::Matches($cmdOutput, $pattern)
if ($results.count -gt 0 )
{
  $item = $results[0] 
  Write-Output $item.Groups[1].Value
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` before running `wsl` you probably want to set a variable to remember the previous encoding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746179/how-do-i-match-on-wsl-output-in-powershell

Comment: @JamesPack thanks for finding the duplicate :)