# wsl --set-default with variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to set the default Linux distribution with user selection in PowerShell script, but can't find any way to set the distribution using variable. Setting the default distribution either with manual command or with hard-coded string in the following script works correctly.

Tried this PowerShell script:

```
$wslList = (wsl --list --quiet)
$wslFilteredList = @()

# To get rid of empty lines in Out-GridView window:
foreach ($item in $wslList) {
    if ("$item" -ne "") {
        $wslFilteredList += $item
    }
}

Write-Output "Choose Linux distribution from pop-up window."
$selectedItem = ($wslFilteredList | Out-GridView -Title "Registered Linux distributions:" -PassThru)

Write-Host "`nSetting selected '$selectedItem' as default Linux distribution."
wsl --set-default "$selectedItem"

Read-Host -Prompt "`nPress Enter to continue"
```

Result:
Getting either wsl usage/help displayed or a message: "There is no distribution with the supplied name."

Expected:
To get the wsl default distribution set.

Additional info:

- I've tried adding $env:WSL_UTF8=1 on the first line of the script and it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67746179/45375), even though you later stated having set `$env:WSL_UTF8=1` before calling `wsl.exe`, which is indeed a *prerequisite*.

The only reasons why the solutions offered in the latter post *wouldn't* work are:

- if your WSL implementation *predates* support for the `WSL_UTF8` environment variable (if `wsl --version` reports *less than `0.64`* under `WSL version:`); in that case, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67746496/45375) to the linked question.
- otherwise, if the distro names contain *non-ASCII*-range characters, because PowerShell would *misinterpret* them.<sup>[1]</sup>

To also account for the latter, use the following:

```bash
# Ensure what wsl's distro-management commands output UTF-8
$env:WSL_UTF8=1

# Call such a command while ensuring that its output is 
# interpreted as UTF-8, and collect its output lines in an array.
[array] $wslFilteredList = 
  & { 

    # Temporarily tell PowerShell to interpret stdout output from
    # external programs as UTF-8.
    $prevEnc = [Console]::OutputEncoding
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

    # Output the names of all distros, which PowerShell relays line by line
    wsl --list --quiet
 
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEnc

  }

# Simulate Out-Grid -PassThru with selecting the *first* distro
$selectedItem = $wslFilteredList[0]

# This should now succeed, even with distro names that contain non-ASCII
# characters.
wsl --set-default $selectedItem
```

---

<sup>[1] *Unless* you've configured your system to use UTF-8 *system-wide*, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375); however, note that doing so has *far-reaching consequences*.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your time, help and expertise. I don't really agree on the duplication, but hopefully then this additional case helps to raise awareness on the topic for other (non-Windows) people with a bit more concrete example.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @R.Adams. I agree that it generally doesn't hurt to have distinct solutions for specific use cases, but all the solution ingredients are present in the linked answer (and unless you truly have distro names with non-ASCII characters, setting `$env:WSL_UTF8=1` before calling `wsl.exe` alone is enough, except if your `wsl.exe` version is very old).