# How I can pass parameter to (Get-PnPUser | ? Email -eq ($SPUserEmail));

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have the following PnP PowerShell script:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$DBServer;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=$DBName")
$conn.Open();
$query = $Query
$dap = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($query,$conn);
$dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable;
$null = $dap.Fill($dt)
foreach($r in $dt.Rows) {
    $SPUserEmail = $r["email_address"];
    $SPuser = (Get-PnPUser | ? Email -eq ($SPUserEmail));
}
```

But I will always get this error:

```
The specified user could not be found.
```

But if I type the email address manually I will get the user:

```
$SPuser = (Get-PnPUser | ? Email -eq test@test.com);
```

Although when I do `Write-Host $SPUserEmail` I will get `test@test.com`

So what could be the reason?

Comment: Is `$r` a single-item hashtable? I couldn't see why filtering through `Where-Object` would give you that error if it wasn't passed directly to the cmdlet via a parameter

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `$r` is a value returned from SQL server

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i posted more code

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `$r`. Does `Get-PNPUser` return a list of users?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `$R` IS `System.Data.DataRow` .. AND `Get-PNPUser` return one user only

Comment: If `? Email -eq test@test.com` works, the implication is that `$r["email_address"]` either doesn't return a _single value_ or, if it does, that that value contains _hidden control characters_.

Comment: @mklement0 it will return a single value because when i write this `Write-Host $SPUserEmail` I will get `test@test.com`

Comment: Inspect your string for unexpected hidden control characters. A quick way to do that is character-by-character inspection with `& { [int[]] [char[]] $Args[0] | % { '0x{0:x} [{1}]' -f $_, [char] $_ } } $yourString`. A more sophisticated way is via the `Debug-String` function, available [as an MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1), as demonstrated in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648684/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 i tried this `Write-Host & { [int[]] [char[]] $Args[0] | % { '0x{0:x} [{1}]' -f $r["email_address"], [char] $r["email_address"] } } $r["email_address"] ` but i got syntax error

Comment: @johnGu, don't use `Write-Host`,  which is [usually the wrong tool](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/). Just use the command as-is. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240860/45375) explains why `Write-Host` is unhelpful for _visualizing_ results.

Comment: @mklement0 ok `& { [int[]] [char[]] $Args[0] | % { '0x{0:x} [{1}]' -f $r["email_address"], [char] $r["email_address"] } } $r["email_address"]` will return this error `Cannot convert value "test@test.com" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."`

Comment: @johnGu, that's not the command I suggested; notably, only the `$yourString` part of it needed substitution with your specific value, `$r["email_address"]`

Comment: @mklement0 so what i need to do?

Comment: @johnGu, that's not what I get when I run `& { [int[]] [char[]] $Args[0] | % { '0x{0:x} [{1}]' -f $_, [char] $_ } }  'test@test.com'`

Comment: @mklement0 this what i will get `0x74 [t]
0x65 [e]
0x73 [s]
0x74 [t]
0x40 [@]
0x74 [t]
0x65 [e]
0x73 [s]
0x74 [t]
0x2e [.]
0x63 [c]
0x6f [o]
0x6d [m]`

Comment: @mklement0 so not sure where is the issue now?

Comment: That is the expected result - do you get the same result with `$r["email_address"]` instead of literal `'test@test.com'`? If so, then I'm out of ideas. Try to provide a [mcve] or as close as you can get to one.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I ran into the same issue, specifically using Get-PnPUser in a foreach loop. For whatever reason, I could only get it to work by pipelining into Get-PnPUser. For example, this did not work:

```
foreach ($GroupId in $GroupIds) {
  $SPGroupId = (Get-PnPUser | where LoginName -match $GroupId).Id
  #...do something...
}
```

But writing it like this works:

```
foreach ($GroupId in $GroupIds) {
  $GroupDisplayName = (Get-PnPAzureADGroup -Identity $GroupId).DisplayName
  $GroupId = ($GroupDisplayName | Get-PnPUser).Id
  #...do something...
}
```

My first post on SO. Hope this helps someone!