# Make control/invisible characters visible in PowerShell `Write-*` cmdlets

Tags: powershell, control-characters

### Background

I have a PowerShell script that reads some cell values from `.xlsx` files and validates them.
This script sometimes reports errors at apparently normal cells. I investigated these cells and found that these cells contain control characters (e.g. tab) in their value.

### Problem

I want to show the cell value in error messages, but control characters are invisible when you show a message with `Write-*` cmdlets like:

```
PS C:\> $message = "`t"
PS C:\> Write-Warning ("Cell Value: [{0}]" -F $message)
WARNING: Cell Value: [ ]
PS C:\>
```

I couldn't recognize what control characters are contained in the message.

### Question

I want to make control characters in error messages visible to recognize what control characters are contained in the message at a glance.

Is there any way to make control/invisible characters visible in `Write-*` cmdlets?
I assume control/invisible characters like:

- ASCII C0/C1 control characters (CR, LF, HT, VT, ...)
- Unicode control characters (ZWSP, LRM, RLM, ...)

Comment: One option is to use the `Debug-String` function, available [as an MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1), as demonstrated in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648684/45375). However, it doesn't represent non-ASCII-range control characters symbolically, only by code point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make a function to replace those with a list of known control characters.

Only downside in that approach is that you have to manually define the control characters you want to replace.

Just tested it and this worked for me:

```
function Show-ControlCharacters {
    param (
        [string]$inputString
    )

    $visualMap = @{
        "`0" = '<NUL>'; "`a" = '<BEL>'; "`b" = '<BS>'; "`t" = '<HT>'; "`n" = '<LF>'; "`r" = '<CR>'; "`e" = '<ESC>'; "`f" = '<FF>'; "`v" = '<VT>'
        # Add more mappings as needed
    }

    foreach ($key in $visualMap.Keys) {
        $inputString = $inputString -replace $key, $visualMap[$key]
    }

    return $inputString
}

$message = "`t"

Write-Warning ("Cell Value: [{0}]" -F (Show-ControlCharacters($message)))
```

I hope it helps

Edit: The regex escape was redundant. But I think the return makes the intention of returning the value clearer. Thx @js2010

Comment: Nice.  Works with emojis too.  You don't need "return", but it works.

Comment: I don't think you need the [regex]::escape(), but it works.